# What is causing my cursor to freeze?

Tags: cursor

I have been using Ubuntu for a number of years now. I updated to the 20.04.1 version earlier this year. Since then I have not added new hardware or made any major software changes except downloading the Raylib libraries to try to learn some game development. A few weeks ago I started to notice that my cursor would occasionally freeze then after a while restart. Lately this has been occurring more often and with a longer period of frozen status. I have tried to research the issue and have found little to give me insight into what the cause might be. I have switched between all three display managers but the issue seems not to be effected. I have had the system monitor active during one episode, but so nothing that would indicate a problem.  There was no increased CPU or memory use or unusual network activity. I have a Nvidia graphics adapter and am using 2 displays. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: OK, I feel a little foolish.  The problem may have been a failing battery in the mouse.  During the last episode I had turned the trackpad on, which I usually have disabled because I accidentally hit it and move my cursor, and discovered that I could still move the cursor and click.  I have changed the battery, so we shall see.  In the past, when the battery got weak, the cursor movement would fail completely not become intermittent.